# How to set a clicking clock in a pygame window

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame-clock

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame
import sys
import datetime
import time


class TextPicture(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, speed, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        text = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
        time_text = font.render(text, 1, [0, 0, 0])  # show now time
        self.image = time_text
        self.speed = speed
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

    def move(self):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speed)
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.left > screen.get_width() - self.image.get_width():
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.top > screen.get_height() - self.image.get_height():
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])
my_time_picture = TextPicture([1, 1], [50, 50])


while 1:
    screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
    my_time_picture.move()
    screen.blit(my_time_picture.image, my_time_picture.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

I am designing a clock which can move in the screen. But what my code can do now is to show a invariant time. I want to clicking and count the time.
   [My invariable clock picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4bhP.png)

And I want to make my clock more beautiful, but don't know how. I will be super grateful if anyone can make any suggestions.

Comment: Your clock does not update because you never update its value...

Comment: "How do I make my clock more beautiful?" is not an on-topic question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: How can I update the value of my clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by using [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to make "tick events" be generated which cause the clock's image to be updated when encountered in the event processing loop.

To make implementing this easier, an `update()` method could be added to the `DigitalClock` class (which is what I renamed your generic `TextPicture` class) which only updates the image, but leaving the current location alone:

```
import datetime
import sys
import time
import pygame

class DigitalClock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, speed, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.speed = speed
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(location, (0, 0))  # placeholder
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        location = self.rect.left, self.rect.top  # save position
        time_text = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.image = self.font.render(time_text, 1, [0, 0, 0])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location  # restore position

    def move(self):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speed)
        if (self.rect.left < 0
            or self.rect.left > screen.get_width()-self.image.get_width()):
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
        if (self.rect.top < 0
            or self.rect.top > screen.get_height()-self.image.get_height()):
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]
```

Following that, you'd need to modify the processing to be something along these lines:

```
pygame.init()
framerate_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])
my_digital_clock = DigitalClock([1, 1], [50, 50])
TICK_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(TICK_EVENT, 1000)  # periodically create TICK_EVENT

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == TICK_EVENT:
            my_digital_clock.update()  # call new method
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
    my_digital_clock.move()
    screen.blit(my_digital_clock.image, my_digital_clock.rect)

    framerate_clock.tick(60)  # limit framerate
    pygame.display.flip()
```

You could make it more beautiful by using a different font and color. Generally anything that made it look more realistic would be an improvement. It might be cool to make the colons between the digit characters blink on and off (using a similar technique).